# Taylor remainder

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have two doubts about Taylor remainder that I hope you can help me with.
Let $f \in C^2(a,b) \cap C^0[a,b]$, where $[a,b]$ is an interval on the real line, and let $R_2(y,x)$ be the remainder of the second order Taylor expansion around $x$, i.e.
$$R_2(y,x) = f(y) - p_2(y,x)$$
I know that $R_2(y,x) = o(|y-x|^2)$, i.e: for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that:
$$|R(y,x)| \leq \epsilon |y-x|^2$$
But does the $\delta$ depend on $x$ or I can find a $\delta$ which is good for every $x$? I'm probably not seeing something obvious here.

Again, I have the same remainder and say that $R(y,x) \leq M$ since it is continuous (on a compact) as a function of $y$. So I should write, more correctly, $$R(y,x) \leq M_x$$
But can I also state that it is limited as a two-variable function?

Thanks to anyone who will help!

Comment: $p (y,x_1)\neq p (y,x_2) $ thue $\delta $ and $M $ depend on $x $.

Comment: The $\delta $ is more or less the modulus of continuity of $f''$. Under these assumptions $f''$ may or may not be uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So, assuming $f''$ continuous on all $[a,b]$ should fix both problems, right (meaning that its limits at the boundary exist finite)? Because then $R$ would be uniformly continuous as a two-variable function.

Comment: Yes, then there should be a uniform $\delta$ independent of $x$. (On the other hand, even in this situation it might be highly suboptimal to actually *use* this uniform $\delta$ at "most" values of $x$.)

Comment: I only needed a uniform delta for my calculation, so it will be okay. But what do you mean by "highly suboptimal"?

Comment: Just that you could get a bound which is way worse than the actual situation, if the second derivative changes a lot more in one region than another.

Comment: Ah, okay! Thanks for your explanations :)